# How to set Mac to open URLs in certain profile of Google Chrome?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

Google Chrome has a feature where you can create several different [browser users](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en).
Is there a way to make Mac OS to use a particular user when opening links from other applications (e.g. skype, MS Word, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how Windows is works,

`chrome www.google.com --profile-directory="Profile 0"` opens urls with "Profile 0"

Profiles are stored in Windows

`C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

```
drwx------+ 1 ahmed          Yok       0 Nov  4 18:19 Default
drwxrwx---+ 1 ahmed          Yok       0 Nov  4 18:26 Profile 0
drwx------+ 1 ahmed          Yok       0 Nov  4 18:28 Profile 1
```

Now you can create aliases to your `.profile` file or create launchers for different profiles.

Comment: Mac works differently and as far as I know it's not possible to do that in mac, because of the way it opens applications (hint: if the application is already running it's not going to open a new instance, but send a signal to running instance instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Velja](https://sindresorhus.com/velja) app for this. It lets you create a rule that says that when you click a link in a specific app, like Skype, it should open the link in a specific Chrome profile.